# Не показывать текст на сайте, если юзер сидит с андроида

Tags: html, javascript

Нужен какой-нибудь скрипт, чтобы не показывать определённый текст на сайте, если юзер сидит с андроида.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    // some code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

И советую прочитать: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html